# How to add FASM support to CMake

Tags: assembly, cmake, fasm

does anyone know how to add  [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) support to CMake? I've tried an original guide [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Assembler) , but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: `I've tried an original guide here , but it doesn't work for me.` - Elaborate, **what exactly** doesn't work.

Comment: I just made a mistake - forgot to include path to fasm in my system's PATH variable . I'm new here so should I post a complete solution here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So , I managed to add three files as said [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Assembler#How_to_add_support_for_other_assembler_.22dialects.22)  in my `CMake\share\cmake-3.7\Modules\` directory (I'm using Windows ):

- **CMakeDetermineASM_FASMCompiler.cmake** :

  ```
  set(ASM_DIALECT "_FASM")
  set(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER_LIST fasm)
  include(CMakeDetermineASMCompiler)
  set(ASM_DIALECT)
  ```
- **CMakeTestASM_FASMCompiler.cmake**:

  ```
  set(ASM_DIALECT "_FASM")
  include(CMakeTestASMCompiler)
  set(ASM_DIALECT)
  ```
- **CMakeASM_FASMInformation.cmake**:

  ```
  set(ASM_DIALECT "_FASM")
  set(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS s;asm)
  set(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER> <SOURCE> <OBJECT>")
  include(CMakeASMInformation)
  set(ASM_DIALECT)
  ```

**Do not forget to include FASM directory to your Path variable**

And it works gracefully!

Answer (score 3):

@alexfsx 's answer works perfectly, do not forget to add `enable_language(ASM_FASM)` into `CMakeLists.txt`. In this case it's also better to keep *.cmake files with project by placing them to e.g. `cmake` subfolder and adding it to the module search path:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
```